# jquery ajax sending data with special character

Tags: jquery

i have wriiten a jquery ajax code of posing comment..

```
function PostComment()
{

   $.ajax({
         type :"POST",
         url:PageUrl+'Post_LectureComment',
         data:"{Comment:'"+$('#txt_PostComment').val()+"',LectureID:'"+87+"',CategoryID:'"+2+"',Author_Id:'"+ 78+"' }",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success:SuccessHandler ,  
         });

         function SuccessHandler(data)
         {}
}
```

when i am sending data in txt_PostComment with ' like =durgesh'rao it is showing error

**Request Payload:
{Comment: 'durgesh'rao',LectureID:'1250',CategoryID:'2',Author_Id:'135' }**

is any way to send data with ' ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you r trying to build JSON object that contain the `'` character. So to solve the this problem you need first to handle the strings with `'`

```
function replacequote(text) {
    var newText = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == "'") {
            newText += "\\'";
        }
        else
            newText += text[i];
    }
    return newText;
};


function PostComment()
{
   $.ajax({
         type :"POST",
         url:PageUrl+'Post_LectureComment',
         data:"{Comment:'" + replacequote($('#txt_PostComment').val()) + "',LectureID:'"+87+"',CategoryID:'"+2+"',Author_Id:'"+ 78+"' }",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success:SuccessHandler ,  
         });

         function SuccessHandler(data)
         {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to build an object using a String literal.  Simply create a new object and set the appropriate properties.

```
$.ajax({
         type :"POST",
         url:PageUrl+'Post_LectureComment',
         data:{comment: $('#txt_PostComment').val(),lectureID:"87",categoryID:"2",author_Id:"78"},
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success:SuccessHandler  
         });
```

Comment: ur method not working in my case.. showing error ..Request URL:http://localhost:6459/SkyLearning/DL/WebService_SKY.aspx/Post_LectureComment
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error;  request payload::Comment=furgesdh&LectureID=1250&CategoryID=2&Author_Id=135

Comment: a 500 server error usually means something went wrong on the server's side. have you looked at your server's error log? (like PHP Error Log) to see why you are getting a 500 error?

Comment: @^ i have send data as         data:{Comment:$('#txt_PostComment').val(),LectureID:$('.lbl_LectureID').text(),CategoryID:"2",Author_Id:$('#content_Type').attr('data-lectureauthorid')},  but not working..

Comment: in browser preview i have seen..{"Message":"InvalidJSONprimitive:Comment.","StackTrace":"atSystem.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\natSystem.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32depth)\r\natSystem.Web.Script.Serializat....

Comment: I updated give it a shot.  (removed extra comma, lowercased property names)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit you query.
As for you `'` is the problem creator, while searching you can make the query like this:

```sql
SET ESCAPE "'"
SELECT * FROM x_table WHERE txt_PostComment with ' like "%durgesh'rao%";
```